'item/start' with type/format 'String/date-time' is not convertible to type/format 'String/date-no-tz'.'
I want to build a flow to transfer a calendar in a list in my TEAMS to my Outlook.
But I have a problem when I save my flow.
Here is my code:
{
  "type": "OpenApiConnection",
  "inputs": {
    "parameters": {
      "table": "...=",
      "item/subject": "@triggerBody()?['Title_x0020_Category']",
      "item/start": "@triggerBody()?['Beginday']",
      "item/end": "@triggerBody()?['Endday']",
      "item/timeZone": "(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
    },
    "host": {
      "apiId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_office365",
      "connection": "shared_office365",
      "operationId": "V4CalendarPostItem"
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {},
  "runtimeConfiguration": {
    "staticResult": {
      "staticResultOptions": "Enabled",
      "name": "Create_event_(V4)0"
    }
  }
}


Error:

Flow save failed with code 'OpenApiOperationParameterValidationFailed' and message 'Input parameter 'item' validation failed in workflow operation 'Create_event_(V4)': The parameter with value '"@triggerBody()?['Beginday']"' in path 'item/start' with type/format 'String/date-time' is not convertible to type/format 'String/date-no-tz'.'.


The error message suggests that the value for item/start is in the wrong format. It should be in the String/date-no-tz format, but it is currently in the String/date-time format.
You can use the convertTimeZone function in Power Automate to convert the date format.

The error message suggests that the value for item/start is in the wrong format. It should be in the String/date-no-tz format, but it is currently in the String/date-time format. You can use the convertTimeZone function in Power Automate to convert the date format.
